# traefik ingressroute - URL should redirect to a default path

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, ingress-route

kubernetes ingress rules, AWS ALB rule has default path rule if no path is provided in the URL.
I couldn't figure out similar config in Traefik ingressroute.
*Right now - https://example.com goes to the default wildfly page.
https://example.com/foo goes to the app login page.
How do I configure so that https://example.com would directly go to https://example.com/foo*

```
Ingressroute:
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
    middlewares:
      - name: https-redirect
        namespace: ns
    services:
    - name: service-1
      port: 80
```

Another ingressroute:

```
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`example.com`)
      kind: Rule
      middlewares:
        - name: https-redirect
      services:
        - name: service-1
          port: 80
```

Middleware:

```
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: https-redirect
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    scheme: https
    permanent: true
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `Traefik` docs, you can create a typical `defaultBackend` Kubernetes `Ingress` like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: cheese

spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: stilton
      port:
        number: 80
```

You can then set priority for this `Ingress` to ensure it matches the right type of requests, as `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.priority` annotation. You can read more about this [here](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/#global-default-backend-ingresses).